# Angular component selector not found

Tags: angular

Is there a way to find all angular selector not found errors at compile time? My angular application is so big that if I change angular component selector names, the angular compiler does not throw an error on `ng serve`

Are there any linters or compiler options that tell us if there are any component selector name specific issues?

Comment: provide a code for the sample we will be more clear.

Comment: have you already tried to use the linter (like ESLint) with some precise rules?

Comment: @Elidor00 adding ESLint would only show error in typeScript files for selector violations. Are there any for template files?
@Sumitpatel to answer your question, if I change the selector name from `foo` to `bar`, angular isn't throwing an error if some template that uses the component is called via `<foo></foo>`